# Отстутствие перевода у уведомлении об открытии очереди проверок "Сообщения низкого качества"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Захожу я такой в очередь сообщений низкого качества и выскакивает мне это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Очевидно**, что тут все как-то не по-русски, поэтому предлагаю перевод:

> Вы получили (открыли) доступ к очереди проверок Сообщения низкого качества! ... Эта очередь содержит посты, которые были распознаны системой или отмечены другими участниками как потенциально проблематичные. Вы можете выбрать одну из следующих опций: выглядит хорошо, редактировать или удалить. Как стоит проверять посты в этой очереди: * Вы можете оставить комментарий, если это необходимо, * Удаляйте ответы к старым вопросам, если они излишни и не добавляют значимой информации к уже имеющимся ответам. ... Узнать больше об очереди Сообщения низкого качества

P.S. Про то, почему это сообщение впервые выскочило мне, когда у меня уже рейтинг больше 2300, а нужен 2000, я вообще молчу...

Comment: Переводы предлагаются [тут](https://ru.traducir.win/). Окно выскочило, потому что его недавно добавили.

Answer (score 2):

Утвердил предложенные на https://ru.traducir.win/ переводы.

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.4.20.39115